# Rectangles formed from every tetromino, tromino and domino

Tags: mathematics, geometry, combinatorics, polyomino

Can you form a 4x7 rectangle from every [tetromino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino), [tromino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino) and [domino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_(mathematics))? There are 5 different tetrominoes, 2 trominoes and 1 domino. Can you find different arrangements that are not mirrors/rotations of each other?

**Bonus question:** can you also form a 2x14 rectangle with the same shapes?

Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For completeness, all the solutions, excluding rotations and reflections.

> 1522 for the 4x7 and 84 for the 2x14.
>  [image]
>  [image]

Answer (score 3):

Simlar to Dr Xorile, I think there are many solutions. Here are several:

> The first one here is my first attempt, it was quite easy. The others are just mutations of it.
>
> ```
>  _____________ 
> |  ___|_____| |
> |_|_  |_   _|_|
> |   |___|_|_  |
> |___|_______|_|
>  _____________ 
> |  ___|_____| |
> |_|_   _|  _|_|
> |   |_|___|_  |
> |___|_______|_|
>  _____________ 
> |  ___|_______| 
> |_|_  |_   _| |
> |   |___|_| |_|
> |___|_____|___|
>  _____________ 
> |  ___|_____| | 
> |_|_  |_   _|_|
> |  _|___|_|   |
> |_|_______|___|
>  _____________ 
> | |_____|___  | 
> |_|_  |_   _|_|
> |   |___|_|_  |
> |___|_______|_|
> ```

Comment: +1 for the asci art! That's cool!

Answer (score 2):

Here's 2 fundamentally different solutions:

> [image: 4x7]

I suspect there are many because these are literally the first two things I tried as I was playing around and in both cases I was able to just shove the pieces in and get a solution. I did it in the numerical order shown.

Answer (score 2):

And here are a few 2x14 solutions:

> ```
>  
> 11222444556778
> 11333345566888
>
> 11133344566788
> 12222445557788
>
> 11222444467788
> 11233355666778
> ```